# Vim colorscheme warnings

Tags: vim, putty

I'm trying to use [Astronaut](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/colors/astronaut.vim) in vim. My ssh client is putty. Never used putty before, but in this company only windows allowed as desktops. I've never had any problems using urxvt through ssh. is this putty color limitation? any solution to make this colortheme work?

I've got these warnings:

```
Error detected while processing /root/.vim/colors/astronaut.vim:
line   22:
E492: Not an editor command: ^M
line   23:
E474: Invalid argument: background=dark^M
line   24:
E411: highlight group not found: clear^M
line   25:
E15: Invalid expression: exists( "syntax_on" )^M
line  165:
E171: Missing :endif
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^M` means that you are using a file with Windows line endings on a UNIX-y machine. Fix the line endings and you'll be fine.

[This page on the Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) has all the information you need. Here is a quick solution:

```
:%s/<C-v><CR>//
```

The `<C-v><CR>` sequence is used to insert a real `^M`.

Comment: `<C-v>` it's Ctrl+v, and what is `<CR>`?

Comment: Seems to be `<C-m>`

Comment: `:h key-notation`